# No option to Renew membership of my already live app in Apple Developer Program

Tags: app-store, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I have a live app which has been on App Store for almost 2+ years now which was being used by clients.

My Apple Developer account had expired around 2 months ago. I have been trying to renew the Apple Developer account ever since through Developer app on Mac and iPhone (from the Account Holder's account) but I am unable to see "Renew" button anywhere.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oiBl.png)

If I go to Apple Developer website on Safari, I see this message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV35f.png)

In middle of last year, I switched my AppleId from user1@xyz.com to user2@xyz.com for business reasons.
The transition was smooth and did not throw any problems then.

I have accepted all the licences and agreements (Apple Developer Program License Agreement and Apple Developer Agreement).

I am not even getting the toggle option for "Auto Renewal" under "Membership Details" in the Apple Developer website on Safari like most of the people were getting here. I have already uploaded the asked $99 from App Store that is asked as Annual Membership fee incase Auto renewal is on but the amount is still not transferred.

I checked even in the Subscriptions under my Apple Id but there also I could not see any mention of my Developer account.

Some suggestions were to go into CSS and look for Renew button but I wasn't able to find there also.

Is it because of change in AppleId mid year which can be causing this error? If this is, then why allow switching AppleId in the first place and mess up everything?

I know there are already hundreds of similar question up here and in Apple Developer Community forum but almost none of the solutions seem to be working in my case.

I have even tried mailing the Apple Support but I have not yet received any response from them. When I called them, they took my one hour only to end up telling me to mail them which I have been doing in the first place.

Apple does not have any official documentation regarding this. Whatever "documentations", they have are outdated and do not reflect with the ground reality. If someone takes a look in Community Forum, it is clearly seen this issue dates back 7-8 years but no steps have been taken to resolve this problem despite being faced by hundreds and thousands of developers for so many years, world over. It is frustrating that a billion dollar company has taken us developers for granted. Their callous attitude is highly infuriating.

Any help on the above would be highly helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why apple do this exactly, but you should open `developer.apple.com` from a safari browser from an iPhone that have iOS 17 or more.
I know this is hard to believe but this is apple for you.

also sometimes the button is not visible but it is there, you can play around with accessibility options to show it.